# Spy++ alternative that can send messages

Tags: winapi, message

Any good alternative for Spy++ that allows sending messages to windows?

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you don't like about Spy++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/).
Use its Window Info tool or spy++ to find a window, and Autoit script editor to send messages.

Answer (score 7):

[Window Detective](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowdetective/) is Open Source, why not modify it?

Answer (score 2):

[SendMessage](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/SendMessage.html) is one of a handful of tools I use from the Stefan of TortoiseSVN fame.

Answer (score 1):

Give Winspector a try . It performs all functons that r in spy++ plus much more
[Winspector - Software Informer Link](http://winspector.software.informer.com/1.0/)

Software Informer Download link is no longer valid, but here's a WayBackMachine [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090916053057/http://www.windows-spy.com:80/)